# R won't detect a given element

Tags: r

The following code won't detect the written element and always gives 0 (false) response in the plant column.

```
ourData <- myData %>% 
mutate(plant = ifelse(description %in% c("⚰️"), 1,0))
View(ourData)
```

The following code gives data below

ourData_ description

[image]

However, it seems to work for the "num_row" column. So I was wondering why this is the case and how I can solve it?

```
ourData <- myData %>% 
mutate(plant = ifelse(num_row %in% c("1"), 1,0))
View(ourData)
```

Below is one for num_row (which works)

ourData_num_row

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide sample input in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) rather than an image. We cannot test your code with the image. Note that `%in%` only does complete matches. For example `"a" %in% "cab"` returns false. If you want partial string matching, you probably want something like `grep` or a function from the `stringr` package.

Comment: As MrFlick said, try with `mydata$plant <- as.integer(grepl("⚰️", myData$description))`